# Are the pullback functors of adjoint functors also adjoint?

Tags: ct.category-theory, sheaf-theory, adjoint-functors

Given adjoint functors $F: A \to B$, $G: B \to A$, if you then take their pullback functors $F^* : Set^B \to Set^A$ and $G^* : Set^A \to Set^B$ given by pre-composition, are these two also adjoint (assuming conditions for their adjoints to exist)? According to wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor_category, this is true for post-composition, is it true for pre-composition? I realise these functors have Kan extensions as adjoints but can find nothing in the literature about taking the Kan extension along the adjoint of a functor.

Comment: If $F \dashv G$, then $G^\ast \dashv F^\ast$. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: However, for the precompositions $F^\ast: Set^{B^{op}} \to Set^{A^{op}}$ and $G^\ast: Set^{A^{op}} \to Set^{B^{op}}$, we do have $F^\ast \dashv G^\ast$ if $F \dashv G$.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant :) Ah ok, it's true for $Set^{A^{op}}$? Do you know of where I could find a proof? Because surely then I could just apply this to the opposite functors $F^{op}: A^{op} \to B^{op}$ etc to get the result I need

Comment: It's an easy exercise if you use the definition of adjunction with the triangle identities.

Comment: Charles, in case there was misunderstanding, my last comment was to apply to functors $F: A \to B$ and $G: B \to A$, which induce functors $Set^{B^{op}} \to Set^{A^{op}}$ and $Set^{A^{op}} \to Set^{B^{op}}$ in a hopefully obvious manner.

Answer (score 3):

This is best understood via the bicategorical characterization of adjunctions in terms of unit and counit 2-morphisms. It is then clear that any bifunctor preserves adjunctions in the obvious sense. And taking presheaf categories and pullback functors is clearly a bifunctor from (small categories)$^{op}$ to categories.

Comment: I've usually heard the term bifunctor used to describe a functor from a product of categories (by analogy with bilinear map). Do you mean a [pseudofunctor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pseudofunctor) or a strict 2-functor? I'm not too familiar with higher category theory.

Comment: I mean a 2-functor. Many people call (weak) 2-categories bicategories.